# Removing markup from select tag option value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am using a combination of rails and jquery datatables for a current project. The code below is being used to manipulate the table into a single view for mobile and append a select tag for filtering.

```
$('#ticket_list').DataTable( {

  "columnDefs": [
    {
        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
            if(type === 'display'){
                data = '<span class="client-data"> ' + data + ' </span>' 
                    + '<span class="priority-data"> ' + row[1] + ' </span>' 
                    + '<span class="status-data"> ' + row[2] + ' </span>' 
                    + '<div class="subject-data"> ' + row[3] + ' </div>'
                    + '<i class="fa fa-user"></i><span class="agent-data"> ' + row[4] + ' </span>'
                    + '<span class="date-data"> ' + row[5] + ' </span>';
                }

                return data;
        },
        "targets": 0
    },        
    { "visible": false, "targets": [ 1,2,3,4,5 ]}
    ],     
    "columns": [
        { "title": "" }
    ],
    "pageLength": setPageLength(),
    "dom": '<"#search-box"f> rt <"#pagination.col-xs-12"p> <"#table-information.col-xs-12"i>',
    language: {
        search: "_INPUT_",
        searchPlaceholder: "Search"
    }, 
    "ordering": false,
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns([0,1,2]).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="col-sm-4" ><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( ".ticket-filtering" )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
                    console.log(val)
                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    },
} );
```

One of the Columns is populated with a span tag styled to take the form of a button / alert. Unfortunately the `select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )` line is also grabbing the span tags causing the following HTML:

`<option value="span class=" priority-data-low"="">Low</option>`

Can anyone recommend the best way to either ensure that the option tag only displays the value="Low" or remove it after it is appended.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It works in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9affnqz/).